# Sending files using aws sync

Tags: aws-cli

I'm using the aws sync command to have jenkins send files to s3. Problem is that aws sync sends the same file again even though it has the same file name as the one in s3. That is because we have to tar then untar the file before sending to s3 and tarring and untar changes the modification time. Is there anyway to send files to s3 more efficiently so that the same file does not get sent?

Comment: Is your Jenkins server on an ec2 instance?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can specify the `--size-only` flag to make the size of each object the only criteria used to decide whether to sync from source to destination. ([docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html))

Comment: The key is the identifier of the object. So when looking at each key, it will only examine the size of the object rather than any metadata. I edited my answer to be more clear.

Comment: that won't work because the file might have changed and still be the same size.

Comment: Then right now there's no good solution currently in the CLI. ETag checking isn't implemented because we can't reliably calculate the ETag for files uploaded in multiple parts.